# How to install package in "R" namely "questionr"

Tags: r

Please help me solve this error in "R", I tried with with many packages and still this error is occurring:

```
 library(agricolae)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘agricolae’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘questionr’
```

Comment: You may want to uninstall and reinstall packages Matrix and sf, then reinstall agricolae. See this thread: https://community.rstudio.com/t/agricolae-package/25507/10

Answer (score 0):

`install.packages("agricolae", dep = TRUE)
 install.packages("questionr", dep = TRUE)`

These will install the packages with their dependencies, also uninstalling and reinstalling the dependency packages would worth a shot as well